# Failure in installing Octave in conda

Tags: package, octave, conda

When trying to install octave in conda, I used this command provided in conda's website:

```
conda install -c conda-forge octave
```

But during the installation, this error occured:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==11.0=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 11.0
```

If my understanding of the message is correct, it says that octave requires cuda driver of version 11.0, however I do have the version 11.0. What went wrong during the process?